# Флаги не переведены

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, тревоги

Когда жмёшь флаг - выскакивает сообщение. Непереведённое:

> [image: Thanks for flagging!]

Comment: Так не жмите флаг!

Comment: С размерами баннера что-то странное творится, кстати.

Answer (score 5):

Не стал мудрствовать лукаво, перевёл так:

> Ваша тревога будет рассмотрена. Спасибо!

Если есть какие-то замечания, предложения - welcome. 
На сайте появится после череды обновлений, скорее всего не раньше понедельника.

Comment: А где ремарка о том, что к флагам "мы" относимся серьёзно? Вдруг для новичков это что-то значит?

Comment: @Other "Ваша тревога будет серьёзно рассмотрена" или "Серьёзно! Ваша тревога будет рассмотрена" :-D

Comment: Надо же показать что у нас тут тоталитаризм и шутить с флагами нельзя!

Comment: @Other тогда можно так: "Спасибо! Тов.майор рассмотрит вашу тревогу с полной серьёзностью."

Comment: И иконку добавить: https://naviny.by/media/2014.05_w3/proslushka-fsb.jpg

Comment: «Ваш з̶в̶о̶н̶о̶к̶ репорт очень важен для нас»